# Google Measurment Protocol

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Вопрос в следуюещм, у gmp есть возможность передавать payload, где обязательным полем является clientId. Однако есть дополнительное поле UserId. Отправка запросов по Google Measurment Protocol осуществляется с сервера, и получить clientId для отправки запроса по ряду факторов не возможно. Однако, на стороне клиента возможно привязать clientId к UserId (в google tag manager). Отсюда логичный вопрос, зачем мне обязательным полем передавать clientId, если я могу передавать userId и аналитика в теории должна сопоставить этот userId с клиентом. Собственно, как быть в данном случае, т.е действительно ли аналитика сопоставить userId <-> clientId и что передавать вместо clientId в запросах.

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть два типа представлений - по clientId и по userId. Чтобы видеть данные в них, вам нужно соответствующие значения передавать.

ГА по userId не будет самостоятельно объединять clientId, потому что когда clientId еще определен для пользователя, то userId может быть уже не определен.

В самом общем случае clientId и userId связаны отношением многие ко многим и автоматический разбор такого отношения может привести к довольно не понятным данным в отчетах.

Что вы передаете в качестве clientId и userId - ваше дело. Если вам удобнее в качестве идентификатора передавать userId, то используйте его и смотрите отчеты в представлении с userId. В этом случае можете генерировать случайный clientId и указывать его в запросах.

Comment: В момент, когда пользователь логинится на сайте, я могу выполнить привязку clientId - UserId через cookie. Аналитика подключается через gtm и как я понимаю, gtm может прочитать из cookie userId. UserId постоянен на весь период существования пользователя в системе. Собственно, если я сделаю такую привязку, через measurment protocol буду передавать реальный Userid и сгенерированный ClientId, аналитика свяжет эти значения у себя?

Comment: Т.е, если у пользователя будут несколько clientId, видимо он заходил с нескольких устройств.

Comment: Да, если вы будете для пользователя передавать один и тот же userId, то по его значению в представлении с включенным userId вы увидите одного пользователя даже с разными clientId.